# data not showing properly in amcharts

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have made one heat map in the amcharts and its link is

`https://codepen.io/divyeshjesadiya/pen/gOxwOGe`

I have entered some dummy data there but in the map, only the last value is showing after sliding.[image] Like the above image I want to show a map. I have tried it and its link is

```
`https://codepen.io/divyeshjesadiya/pen/MWvjWPY`
```

but in the second codepen link date is not displaying properly in the X-axis. so, I have tried it like in the first codepen link but where map is not working properly and the date is showing properly. you can refer both and help me in where map data and date both show properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could in this instance increase your gridDistance but I don't think this is what you are asking for. In that case I would rotate your x axis labels so try the following to see if this fits what you need:

```
xAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
```

Put this under xAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40; so it would be:

```
xAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;
xAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
```

If I understand your question correctly hopefully this resolves your issue. Also I think the documentation here might be able to shed some light on your issue: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/wrapping-and-truncating-axis-labels/